# Polynomial-time reduction between languages(of problems) in NP and languages(of problems) in P

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, reduction

hello I am having difficulties to understand the topic of P,NP and Polynomial-time reduction.
I have tried to search it on web and ask some of my friends , but i havent got any good answer .

I wish to ask a general question about this topic :

let A,B be  languages ( or set of problems )  in P
let C,D be languages in NP
which of the next are Necessarily true ( may be more than 1)

1. there is a Polynomial-time reduction from A to B
2. there is a Polynomial-time reduction from A to C
3. there is a Polynomial-time reduction from C to A
4. there is a Polynomial-time reduction from C to D

thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) is true (with the exception of `B={}` and `B={all words}`), with the following polynomial reduction:

```
Let w_t be some word such that B(w_t)=true, and w_f be some word such that B(w_f)=false.
Given a word w: Run A(w). If A(w)=true, return w_t - otherwise, return w_f
```

The above is polynomial reduction, because all operartions are polynomial and the output of the reduction yields `B(f(w))=true` if and only if `A(w)=true`.

(2) is true again, with the same reduction (again, if you can assume there is one `w_t` and one `w_f` such as described).

(3) This is wrong, assuming P!=NP.

Assume such a reduction exist, and let it be `f:Sigma*->Sigma*`. 

Examine the problems `C=SAT` and `A` is some problem P, and let `M_A` be a polynomial time algorithm that solves A.

We will show we can solve SAT in polynomial time (but since we assumed P!=NP, it is impossible - contradiction, so `f` does not exist).

Given an instance of SAT `w`, run `w'=f(w)`. Run M_A(w'), and answer the same.

The above is clearly polynomial, and it returns always the correct answer - from the definition of polynomial reduction - `f(w)` is in `A` if and only if `w` is in `C`. 

Thus - the above algorithm solves SAT in polynomial time - contradiction.

(4) Is also wrong, since case (3) is covered in it.